# How would you test a hypothesis that an independent variable has a greater effect on a dependent variable in one country than it does in another?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics

For example, the value of education is greater (in terms of relative wages) in country A than in country B. The independent variable is years of education and the dependent variable is the relative wage.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a place for a regression with an interaction between education and country.

$$
y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{country}+\beta_2x_{education}+\beta_3x_{country}x_{education}
$$

The $\beta_3$ parameter tells you the difference in slope between the two countries. Since you know the type of difference of interest, a one-sided test would be appropriate.

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you so much for your answer. I need a bit more help with the one-sided test... am I testing the possibility of beta_3 being positive?

I am new to statistics and hypothesis testing.